# how many requests does the code below make to the server?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, lxml

```
from lxml import etree
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://mountainproject.com'
driver.get(url) #I know this makes a request
html = driver.page_source #does this line also make a request?
dom = etree.HTML(html) #does this line also make a request?
```

I dont want to be making to many requests to the url so could any clarify if the 5th/6th line of code makes a request to the server?

Thank you.

Comment: driver.page_source communicates to the browser that the webdriver wants the page source returned.  The browser returns it.  The browser does not go to the internet for that.... but the webdriver does communicate with the browser via the wire protocol (locally)  I'm not familiar with etree, but I would say no request made there either.  This assumes a local instance of the webdriver.  Using a remote webdriver the commands are sent over the internet to the server hosting your webdrivers.  Also see: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-page-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually quite a few requests made under the hood when executing your code. I found it makes the following requests:

```
https://mountainproject.com/ 301 text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
https://www.mountainproject.com/ 200 text/html; charset=UTF-8
https://www.mountainproject.com/css/ap-vendor-full.css?id=fa0c443b73aac8a18b4b 200 text/css
https://www.mountainproject.com/css/styles-shared-all.css?id=1e17ec741b720d85e959 200 text/css
https://www.mountainproject.com/css/styles-site-climb.css?id=712703d159d0ec101dd2 200 text/css
https://www.mountainproject.com/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min-3-1-0.css 200 text/css
https://www.mountainproject.com/js/ap-vendor-full.js?id=1945ee864736d4f641db 200 text/javascript
https://www.mountainproject.com/js/sites/all.js?id=a65a925fba88e4d1fc48 200 text/javascript
https://www.mountainproject.com/js/climb-main.js?id=d7aff6c924e13b9f5aa3 200 text/javascript
https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js 200 application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/icons/closeX-lightBg.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/arrows/nextGray.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/social/white-facebook.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/climb/logoHexInvert.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/hamburgerIcon.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/apple.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/climb/logoHex2.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/android.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/fonts/RobotoCondensed700.woff2 200 None
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/arrowLeft.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/fonts/roboto-v19-latin-regular.woff2 200 None
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/arrowRight.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/stars/starBlueHalf.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/stars/starBlue.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/partners/climbingMag.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/js/maps/maps.js?id=b47ec6c62549d52ee912 200 text/javascript
https://cdn2.apstatic.com/photos/climb/114286419_sqsmall_1524441422.jpg 200 image/jpeg
https://www.mountainproject.com/js/components/search/main.js?id=0448767c13131f4c9e6c 200 text/javascript
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/arrowRightBlack.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/appleBlack.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/androidBlack.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/climb/appIcon.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/partners/af-black.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/camera.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://cdn2.apstatic.com/photos/climb/2200035_medium_1557851488.jpg 200 image/jpeg
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/partners/af-4.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/partners/alpinist.png 200 image/png
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/searchWhite.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KX76S82 200 application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/waitWhite.gif 200 image/gif
https://www.mountainproject.com/img/icons/closeX-darkBg.svg 200 image/svg+xml
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-TZ07N3455D&l=dataLayer&cx=c 200 application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js?_=1621032662221 200 text/javascript
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=prepCaptchas&render=explicit 200 text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js 200 text/javascript
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js 200 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-TZ07N3455D&gtm=2oe5c1&_p=1314722123&sr=1792x1120&ul=en-us&cid=103056203.1621032664&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%2F&dt=Rock%20Climbing%20Guides%3A%20Routes%2C%20Photos%20%26%20Forum%20%7C%20Mountain%20Project&sid=1621032663&sct=1&seg=0&en=page_view&_fv=1&_nsi=1&_ss=1 204 text/plain
https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/438433750939555?v=2.9.39&r=stable 200 application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
https://www.mountainproject.com/photos/news/climbing-8e4bb4ceb980b8d477178f8608699457.jpg 200 image/jpeg
https://www.mountainproject.com/photos/news/accessfund-5e92e2476376733db69523c0d9f571c0.jpg 200 image/jpeg
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/loader.js 200 text/javascript
https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=GTM-KHB2CJL&t=gtm2&cid=103056203.1621032664 200 application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/f-bnnOuahiYKuei7dmAd3kgv/recaptcha__en.js 200 text/javascript
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=438433750939555&ev=PageView&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%2F&rl=&if=false&ts=1621032664161&sw=1792&sh=1120&v=2.9.39&r=stable&ec=0&o=30&fbp=fb.1.1621032664160.290931468&it=1621032663879&coo=false&exp=l1&rqm=GET 200 image/gif
https://www.google-analytics.com/j/collect?v=1&_v=j90&a=1314722123&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Rock%20Climbing%20Guides%3A%20Routes%2C%20Photos%20%26%20Forum%20%7C%20Mountain%20Project&sd=30-bit&sr=1792x1120&vp=1200x926&je=0&_u=aCDAAAADQAAAAC~&jid=1618144214&gjid=1075963567&cid=103056203.1621032664&tid=UA-407891-1&_gid=1600094628.1621032664&_r=1&gtm=2wg5c1KX76S82&z=1139774133 200 text/plain
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/css/core/tooltip.css 200 text/css
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/css/util/util.css 200 text/css
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/js/jsapi_compiled_default_module.js 200 text/javascript
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/js/jsapi_compiled_graphics_module.js 200 text/javascript
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/js/jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js 200 text/javascript
https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/j/collect?t=dc&aip=1&_r=3&v=1&_v=j90&tid=UA-407891-1&cid=103056203.1621032664&jid=1618144214&gjid=1075963567&_gid=1600094628.1621032664&_u=aCDAAAACQAAAAC~&z=492030330 200 text/plain
https://www.gstatic.com/charts/50/js/jsapi_compiled_corechart_module.js 200 text/javascript
https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=438433750939555&ev=Microdata&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%2F&rl=&if=false&ts=1621032664666&cd[DataLayer]=%5B%5D&cd[Meta]=%7B%22title%22%3A%22Rock%20Climbing%20Guides%3A%20Routes%2C%20Photos%20%26%20Forum%20%7C%20Mountain%20Project%22%2C%22meta%3Adescription%22%3A%22Find%20rock%20climbing%20routes%2C%20photos%2C%20and%20guides%20for%20every%20state%2C%20along%20with%20experiences%20and%20advice%20from%20fellow%20climbers.%22%7D&cd[OpenGraph]=%7B%22og%3Atitle%22%3A%22Rock%20Climbing%20Guides%3A%20Routes%2C%20Photos%20%26%20Forum%20%7C%20Mountain%20Project%22%2C%22og%3Asite_name%22%3A%22Mountain%20Project%22%2C%22og%3Atype%22%3A%22website%22%2C%22og%3Adescription%22%3A%22Find%20rock%20climbing%20routes%2C%20photos%2C%20and%20guides%20for%20every%20state%2C%20along%20with%20experiences%20and%20advice%20from%20fellow%20climbers.%22%2C%22og%3Aimage%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn2.apstatic.com%2Fclimb%2F111569437_medium_1494295483.jpg%22%2C%22og%3Aurl%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%22%7D&cd[Schema.org]=%5B%5D&cd[JSON-LD]=%5B%5D&sw=1792&sh=1120&v=2.9.39&r=stable&ec=1&o=30&fbp=fb.1.1621032664160.290931468&it=1621032663879&coo=false&es=automatic&tm=3&exp=l1&rqm=GET 200 image/gif
https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js 200 application/javascript
https://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-7h0NMm9UmA2V9.js 200 application/javascript
https://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=1699603804;source=gtm;rf=0;a=p-7h0NMm9UmA2V9;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mountainproject.com%2F;uh=65ce955d6ae6;uht=2;fpan=1;fpa=P0-724355007-1621032665310;pbcn=u;pbc=;ns=0;ce=1;qjs=1;qv=1558287b-20210421211215;cm=;gdpr=0;ref=;d=mountainproject.com;je=0;sr=1792x1120x30;dst=1;et=1621032665310;tzo=420;ogl=title.Rock%20Climbing%20Guides%3A%20Routes%252C%20Photos%20%26%20Forum%20%7C%20Mountain%20Project%2Csite_name.Mountain%20Project%2Ctype.website%2Cdescription.Find%20rock%20climbing%20routes%252C%20photos%252C%20and%20guides%20for%20every%20state%252C%20along%20with%20experi%2Cimage.https%3A%2F%2Fcdn2%252Eapstatic%252Ecom%2Fclimb%2F111569437_medium_1494295483%252Ejpg%2Curl.https%3A%2F%2Fwww%252Emountainproject%252Ecom 200 image/gif
```

How do I know this? This is a perfect use case for [seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/), which automatically captures all http requests made. I just used this code to return all the requests:

```
from lxml import etree
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = 'https://mountainproject.com'
driver.get(url) #I know this makes a request
html = driver.page_source #does this line also make a request?
dom = etree.HTML(html) #does this line also make a request?
for request in driver.requests:

    print(
        request.url,
        request.response.status_code,
        request.response.headers['Content-Type']
    )
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to determine which requests are made by which line of code, maybe someone else can help if you need to figure that out.

Comment: that's all from the get()... I guess this site loads a lot of external resources.  Btw, you may want to remove some of the data there.  It could include session tokens, depending on whether you used a clean profile.  (If you used just the code posted, you're OK as Selenium will create a new temporary profile by default.)